# How to Load Patched Image into Dataloader to Feed on Neural Network

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, dataloader

I have a little problem on understanding how patched image used to train deep learning network. I have some 2D image that relatively large (1700 x 3000 px) that used for semantic segmentation. To avoid high consumption of computational power I did patch the input image to manageable size (360 x 480 px) to feed into the network. The thing that I still don't understand is, let's say after the training process I want the output in the form of probability map of the predicted segmentation region in its original size (1700 x 3000 px), that means I have to stitch back the patched image fed to the network but, what I don't understand is how to have track which patch is belong to the image inputed before (I use batchsize of 8 images). How to build the dataloader, do I need to mark the length of the data (which batch is the start and ending of corresponded patched image) then used it for tracking the parts of the image and stitch it back?

I kind of lost in understanding the logic there.

I use pytorch as the framework, and using nn.Unfold to patch the image.
Any answer to my question is appreciated, Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

So the easiest way would be to make own algorythm for tiling image. You would probably want to have overlapping tiles so you don't loose any information on the edges of tiles.

Example without overlapping (it's just example how to do it - not actually working code)

Splitting

```
horizontal = image.shape[0] // tile_size_x
vertical = image.shape[1] // tile_size_y
indices = []
slices = []
for y in range(vertical - 1):
    for x in range(horizontal - 1):
        tile_indices = [slice(x * tile_size_x, (x + 1) * tile_size_x), slice(y * tile_size_y, (y + 1) * tile_size_y)]
        indices.append(tile_indices)
        slices.append(image[tile_indices])
```

Merging

```
merged = zeros_like(image)
for i in range(len(indices)):
    merged[indices[i]] = slices[i]
```

So in short, you split image into tiles and save them with indices. After prediction, tiles are in the same order as at input so indices on the oryginal image are the same. You just need to put them in the same indice as they came from.

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your response! If i summarize, one way to stitch the image back is to give the patch indices, and after all prediction on patch done, the indices used to stitch the image back right? 
One thing that I want to ask more is about the overlapping tiles, doesn't the overlapping tile affect the prediction, is this will be a problem? Indeed when using non-overlapping tiles we don't lose any edge information. Is this the trade-off to use overlapping and non-overlapping tiles for prediction?

Comment: @Josh068 Right. Overlapping tiles help with maintaining consistency on area while tiles are connected to each other on edges because of how convolution works (padding). Because of padding, there will be few pixels with no important information on edges.